# referencing an html input within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-input

I have a question about to get information out of a input tag that is generated within (nested) ng-repeats.

I have nested objects that get iterated through using ng-repeat.  At the innermost level, I need to take the key, and attach it to a user-inputted value.  (It's the name of a property and how often to sample it.)  However, I cannot seem to be able to access the value of the input field.

I would love to pass the value directly and not have to give the input an ID at all like so:

```
<div class="well" ng-show="showProps == true" ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
  <h5><strong>{{key}}</strong></h5> 
  <h5>Sample Interval:</h5>
  <input id="period" class="form-control" type="number" value="20" step="10" />
  <button ng-click="addToList(device,obj,key,period.value)">add</button>
  <button ng-click="removeFromList(device,obj,key)">remove</button>
</div>



  $scope.addToList = function(device,obj,prop,period) {
    console.log("Sample period: " + period);
  }
```

However, that gave me an undefined error, so I tried giving it an id with the {{$index}} variable and then in the javascript reference it.

```
<div class="well" ng-show="showProps == true" ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
  <h5><strong>{{key}}</strong></h5> 
  <h5>Sample Interval:</h5>
  <input id="period_{{$index}}" class="form-control" type="number" value="20" step="10" />
  <button ng-click="addToList(device,obj,key,{{$index}})">add</button>
  <button ng-click="removeFromList(device,obj,key)">remove</button>
</div>



  $scope.addToList = function(device,obj,prop,period_index) {
    var per = document.getElementById("peroid_{{$perod_index}}").value
    console.log("found a function: " + per);
  }
```

However, that gave me a parse error, so I feel like I'm barking up the wrong tree.  How do I get the value out of there and into javascript?

Comment: Use of `document.getElementById` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. With the AngularJS framework, use the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#overview) to get information out of a input tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want to do but check this out and see if it helps:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope)
{
  $scope.showProps = true;
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.obj = {
    "first": {
      input: 20,
      items: []
    },
    "second": {
      input: 20,
      items: []
    }
  };
  
  $scope.addToList = function(key,value)
  {
    $scope.obj[key].items.push(value);
  };
  
  $scope.removeFromList = function(key, value)
  {
    var index = $scope.obj[key].items.indexOf(value);
    
    if(index != -1)
    {
     $scope.obj[key].items.splice(index, 1);
    }
    
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="well" ng-show="showProps == true" ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
    <h5><strong>{{key}}</strong></h5> 
    <h5>Sample Interval:</h5>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" step="10" ng-model="value.input" />
    <button ng-click="addToList(key,value.input)">add</button>
    <button ng-click="removeFromList(key, value.input)">remove</button>
    <span ng-repeat="item in value.items track by $index"><br>{{item}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sweet! No problem :)